# Why does my laptop suddenly turn off while my battery reports about 24% of charge?

Tags: 14.04, laptop, battery

I have an ASUS K53E.  The battery reports a capacity of about 76.5%, i.e 43.8 Wh of 57.2 Wh.

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, my laptops suddenly turns off: no suspend, hibernate or gracefully shut down, but a drastic lost of power...

This happens when my laptop still reports more than 20% of charge.  It seems that I need to mentally subtract the 100% - 76.5% = 23.5% to see that I need to plug my laptop...

Does anyone else has reported this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have set proper ventilation or cooling pads for your laptop. laptops will shutdown if it is over heated. You can find several articles in net regarding this issue. Google it –  Vembu 2 mins ago

Comment: My sensors indicator says this is not the case: 52ºC... I have setup an alarm when it goes beyond 80ºC...

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue on my HP Pavilion dm4. Laptop turns off on its own randomly when under load. Temperatures not an issue, the laptop works fine when plugged in. I can easily replicate the issue when running intellij idea and re-indexing.

The laptop then only starts when I plug it in.

I also have windows on the laptop and those work ok on battery.